# Email sending control

Tags: javascript, gmail

I would like to implement email sending with my own mail server.

Is there any java script control/library that available that has similar functionality to gmail sending popup.
It shoudl be pretty somple including multiple recipients, subject, body text and send button.

Of course i can implement all this functionality by myself but maybe someone out there already did something similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)
with little customization for the most problematic part of the email sending form.